# Is there a way to create a PayPal donation link (as opposed to a button)?

Tags: hyperlink, paypal

I've looked all over paypal's website and can't find any info on creating a simple text link for a donation.

Anyone have any info?

Answer (score 4):

According to [this link](http://runtingsproper.blogspot.com/2009/07/simple-paypal-button.html), you can use HTTP GET, meaning you can build a URL for a simple link.
Note that this link is written in C#, so you can't actually use this as code reference.

You'll probably need something like

```
<a href="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=email@myserver.com&item_name=...">
```

Make sure to use '&' to separate fields and to encode them properly if they include special characters (such as '&').

Answer (score 1):

Updating the button code from [paypal](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_donate_techview_outside):

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="me@mybusiness.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Team In Training">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="25.00">
    <a href="javascript:document._xclick.submit();">Donate</a>
</form>
```

Comment: So there is no way to do this with just a hyperlink? I want to avoid using a form if at all possible.

Comment: @kylex What do you want to avoid using a form?

Comment: Because the user is entering code through a CMS which strips out the form tag.